# Stateless Vs Stateful rebuild

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, flutter-widget

when a stateless widget is inside a stateful widget it will redraw or not?
now the stateless widget can't be redrawn at run time but stateful can.
the question is when the stateless widget is inside a stateful widget it will be redrawn or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `statelessWidget` which is a `child` of a `statefulWidget` will be rebuilt if the `statefulWidget` rebuilds. Basically, when `setState` is called in a `statefulWidget`, the old state is chucked away and the build method runs with the new state. So if a `statelessWidget` it referenced in the `statefulWidget`'s `build` method, yes it will be rebuilt.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('Stateful widget built');
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Example'),
      ),
      body: BodyWidget(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {});
        },
        tooltip: 'Set state',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BodyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('Stateless widget built');
    return Container(
      child: Text('Stateless widget'),
    );
  }
}
```

Try this example out, when you hit the Fab, it re `setState` on the `statefulWidget` and you will get a print out in the console when each build method is run.

Comment: You can also check out this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d_m5csmrf7I&ab_channel=Flutter

Comment: There are some optimizations if the stateless widget has the same key, I believe.

Comment: Also a package such as provider in use with consumer or selector if you didn't want to rebuild the stateless widget could give some optimizations.